# Нужно ли тире после придаточных условных?

Tags: пунктуация

Если кто-то скажет Вам, что внедрил «Бережливое производство» за три месяца в крупной компании, не верьте.

Если Ваши работники думают о том, как им эффективнее производить продукцию, принимают активное участие в различных экспериментах по усовершенствованию технологии производства,  Вас можно поздравить: на Вашем предприятии есть «Бережливое производство».

Answer (score 2):

Тире возможно, если придаточное условное или уступительное предшествует главной части: "Если кто-нибудь придет и захочет выманить тебя из домика ***- не открывай дверь! "*** - напутствовали гномики Белоснежку. .
В втором примере вы правильно поставили двоеточие, т.к. далее содержится особое предупреждение о последующем разъяснении. 
***В первом примере перед тире  по условиям контекста может оказаться запятая.*** 
***См.: Справочник по русскому языку. Орфография. Пунктуация. Розенталь. Д. Э.***

Comment: Тире возможно, но можно ли в этих случаях ограничиться запятой?

Comment: Вполне, если произносите со спокойной интонацией, если же делаете большую выделительную паузу - лучше поставить тире.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: А для чего "бережливое" с заглавной буквы? Под этим названием официально зарегистрирована какая-то технология, или это ходовая условность, подобная "безлюдной технологии"?